# Why is this JSON not parsing correctly?

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON-file (staff.json):

```
[{
"Position" : "Programmer",
    "Name" : "Giacomo Gulizzoni",
     "Age" : 37,
     "Sex" : "Male",
 "Project" : "SmartFactory"
}, {
"Position" : "Tester",
    "Name" : "Marko Botton",
     "Age" : 34,
     "Sex" : "Male",
 "Project" : "SmartFactory"
}, {
"Position" : "Tester",
    "Name" : "Markn",
     "Age" : 60,
     "Sex" : "Male",
 "Project" : "SmartFactory"
}, {
"Position" : "Tester",
    "Name" : "Mariah Maclachian",
     "Age" : 37,
     "Sex" : "Female",
 "Project" : "SmartFactory"
}, {
"Position" : "Tester",
    "Name" : "Valerie Liberty",
     "Age" : 25,
     "Sex" : "Female",
 "Project" : "SmartProject"
}, {
"Position" : "Programmer",
   "Name " : "Guido Jack Gulizzoni",
     "Age" : 22,
     "Sex" : "Male",
 "Project" : "SmartProject"
}, {
"Position" : "Programmer",
   "Name " : "Guioni",
     "Age" : 44,
     "Sex" : "Male",
 "Project" : "SmartProject"
}]
```

And this code (table-generator.js) generates a table from this json:

```
define('table-generator', function () {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "js/json/staff.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table><tr><th>Position</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Sex</th><th>Project</th></tr>";
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" + 
        arr[i].Position + 
        "</td><td>" + 
        arr[i].Name + 
        "</td><td>" + 
        arr[i].Age + 
        "</td><td>" + 
        arr[i].Sex + 
        "</td><td>" + 
        arr[i].Project + 
        "</td></tr>";
    }

    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
});
```

The problem: when I add more persons to JSON-file, their names in table are generated as Undefined. Only names, other data are displayed correctly. Can't find out, what is the reason (may be require.js). 
Can anybody help me out?
The link to page is in the comment below.

Comment: The page: http://dobraya.hol.es/genesis/

Comment: Remove the space character at the end of the field name : `"Name " : "Guido Jack Gulizzoni",`. "Name", without the ending space.

Comment: Check your console: `TypeError: $ is not a function(…)` Are you supposed to be using jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last two objects in the array have the name keys as "Name " (with a space at the end) and not "Name".

Comment: Oh!  That'it, so simple) Thank you, Tom!

Comment: No worries, things like that are sometimes really difficult to spot when you've been looking at it for some time!